# Kafka consumers lag detection in spring-kafka projects

Tags: apache-kafka, spring-kafka

## Intro

When having a `RecordInterceptor` implemented in our `spring-kafka` project that skips certain events in a partition (returns null for these), the partition offsets are not updated until a message arrives that is not skipped.

Because our app consumes from company-wide topics where only a fraction of events are important to our application, the consumer lag is enormous - **hundreds of thousands** for some specific topics.

Our primary measure to detect that the consumers are being behind with event consumption is the Consumer Lag metric (i.e. detecting we're having throughput issues). However, not having the skipped messages' offsets committed does not help here.

## Questions

1. We were wondering how you guys detect consumers being behind with the consumption (i.e. consumers being too slow), to scale up the number of consumers for example?
2. Is there any way to commit the offsets for the skipped messages as well?

Comment: Not sure if it's what you want, but Burrow is typically used for external lag monitoring

Comment: The problem is that no tool can help if we can't count on the lag metric. Since we have huge lags it appears as if the consumers are behind with the consumption but they're actually not behind at all - they just received a lot of events that were skipped.

Comment: You can "count on it" if it's accurate. The only way lag is accurate, will be when it is moved forward after you commit offsets. Sounds like you're not committing when you're skipping, as indicated by below answer

Comment: This may help you. Please read all the comments. (https://stackoverflow.com/a/76365819/7132691).
I am assuming you are using spring boot v2.7.x and spring kafka 2.8.x.
In summary, you should use 2.9.13; 2.8.x is no longer supported as OSS. spring.io/projects/spring-kafka#support. 2.9.x is fully compatible with Boot 2.7.x. 
I was also facing the same issue But after upgrading to spring kafka 2.9.13, issue is resolved.

Answer (score 0):

I only can say for commits: there is really no hard reason to commit every single record. For subsequent offset from `1` to `100` it is really just enough to commit that `100` - and all the rest are going to be treated as processed. Even if you skip half of them. In the perfect world we never need to commit: the consumer deals with its own cursor. We need to commit offset only for the cases where our consumer fail, so when we start a new one and continue consuming from the place where the last one has left. Not sure how else to explain it. See more info in Apache Kafka docs: https://www.learningjournal.guru/courses/kafka/kafka-foundation-training/offset-management/

Spring for Apache Kafka doesn't detect consumer lag. The `KafkaConsumer` doesn't expose such an option.

Anyway it looks like you can use an `AdminClient` API for that goal: https://www.baeldung.com/java-kafka-consumer-lag

Comment: In my project, we use Confluent Cloud where we see the huge lags for our partitions. What we need is a "reliable" lag that would detect slow consumption. The current way tells us we're behind a lot but we're actually not.

Comment: It sounds like you might be skipping all records received by the poll, which was not anticipated, in that case, we won't commit any offsets. We need to somehow track that situation and commit the last offsets for all the skipped partitions. Please open a new feature request in a GitHub issue. That said, this seems very inefficient to receive and skip so many records.

Comment: @GaryRussell You're right, it might be that all records in the poll are skipped. I'll open a GH issue, thanks!
We wanted to use `RecordFilterStrategy` instead, but we did not find a way to chain multiple filters together. The `CompositeRecordInterceptor` can do that for interceptors, though. Filters seem to commit the offset whatever true/false result they return.

Comment: @GaryRussell Anyway, even filters are not ideal, because these are executed after the interceptors. In our current setup, we do have 3 interceptors that filter out records, and the last interceptor is logging the records that will be consumed (we do not want to log the filtered-out records).
That cannot be easily achieved by combining 3 filters and 1 logging interceptor.

Comment: It would be easy enough to create a composite `RecordFilterStrategy` yourself, and do the logging there rather than in the interceptor.

Comment: @GaryRussell Yeah, we were thinking about that too. It only seems weird to misuse the filter strategy for logging purposes. But I think it will do for the moment.

Comment: I would agree if that's all it is doing, but it seems reasonable to me to delegate to one or more filters and then log any records that are not filtered by them.

Comment: @GaryRussell Today I found out that our logging interceptor begins a new XRay Segment on `intercept` and ends it on `afterRecord`. That prevents me from moving the logging to the filter :( Given that, I'll have to keep it as an interceptor and call the filter chain to detect whether the record will be filtered. That is not nice, but I am afraid it is the only way.