# Duplicate check for spring cloud stream consumers

Tags: java, spring-boot, apache-kafka, spring-cloud-stream, spring-aop

I want to check for duplicate messages in my Spring Cloud Stream Kafka consumers. This is what I have now:

```java
@Component
public class MessageSubscriber {


    @Autowired
    MessageConsumer messageConsumer;

    public Consumer<Message<PlaneEvent>> planeEventConsumer() {
        return event -> messageConsumer.consumePlaneEvent(event);
    }

    @Component
    public static class MessageConsumer {
        
        @Transactional
        @DuplicateCheck(key = "id")
        public void consumePlaneEvent(Message<PlaneEvent> msg) {
            // do something here
        }

    }

}
```

The custom `@DuplicateCheck` annotation uses Spring AOP to intercept the consumer method and checks for duplicates in the database using the specified `key`, and the `kafka_receivedTopic` header from the `Message`.

Is there a recommended pattern or better way to:

- **Intercept functional consumers**. (I am aware about `ChannelInterceptor`, but would **not** prefer to use it because of multiple reasons. ChannelInterceptor intercepts all channels [input and output], and the regex to filter channels will need me to enforce a channel naming scheme. ChannelInterceptor will also complicate skipping the processing of duplicate messages. I'd like something less intrusive.)
- **Get the kafka topic or binding destination in the functional consumer**. Relying on the `kafka_receivedTopic` header seems brittle and inflexible.
- **Handle transactions with functional consumers**. Since the `@Transactional` annotation creates dynamic proxies, I'm having to wrap the consumer logic in another class and create its bean.

These things were a little simpler with the older annotation-based consumers (`@StreamListener`).

Answer (score 0):

You can add a `ListenerContainerCustomizer` bean and add a `RecordInterceptor` to the listener container.

```java
/**
 * An interceptor for {@link ConsumerRecord} invoked by the listener
 * container before and after invoking the listener.
 *
 * @param <K> the key type.
 * @param <V> the value type.
 *
 * @author Gary Russell
 * @since 2.2.7
 *
 */
@FunctionalInterface
public interface RecordInterceptor<K, V> extends ThreadStateProcessor {

    /**
     * Perform some action on the record or return a different one. If null is returned
     * the record will be skipped. Invoked before the listener. IMPORTANT; if this method
     * returns a different record, the topic, partition and offset must not be changed
     * to avoid undesirable side-effects.
     * @param record the record.
     * @param consumer the consumer.
     * @return the record or null.
     * @since 2.7
     */
    @Nullable
    ConsumerRecord<K, V> intercept(ConsumerRecord<K, V> record, Consumer<K, V> consumer);

    /**
     * Called after the listener exits normally.
     * @param record the record.
     * @param consumer the consumer.
     * @since 2.7
     */
    default void success(ConsumerRecord<K, V> record, Consumer<K, V> consumer) {
    }

    /**
     * Called after the listener throws an exception.
     * @param record the record.
     * @param exception the exception.
     * @param consumer the consumer.
     * @since 2.7
     */
    default void failure(ConsumerRecord<K, V> record, Exception exception, Consumer<K, V> consumer) {
    }

    /**
     * Called when processing the record is complete either
     * {@link #success(ConsumerRecord, Consumer)} or
     * {@link #failure(ConsumerRecord, Exception, Consumer)}.
     * @param record the record.
     * @param consumer the consumer.
     * @since 2.8
     */
    default void afterRecord(ConsumerRecord<K, V> record, Consumer<K, V> consumer) {
    }

}
```

Comment: In this pattern how do skip message consumption if there is a duplicate found?

Comment: Return null. Read the javadoc above.

Comment: I'm really sorry. I should have looked more carefully before asking. I assumed it would function similar to the GlobalChannelInterceptor. Returning null with that throws an exception instead of skipping the message.

Comment: @GaryRussell if we return null and ack mode is set to manual the offset is not committed for skipped message. Any workaround for that.

Comment: @Dhananjay the framework cannot make any assumptions when using MANUAL acks - the application may have not ack'd earlier records yet and committing the offset of a skipped record would implicitly ack those records too. The interceptor provides access to the consumer, allowing the interceptor itself to commit the offset, if that is what the application wants.

Comment: @GaryRussellin  i am using version 2.8.0 in that even with auto acknowledgement , offset was not committing. Though in version 3.0.0 i can see fix to ack the current record. Due to our project restrictions cant upgrade to 3.0.0 is there anyway i can customise kafkamessage listener container at project level?

Comment: Overloaded (`default`) methods including the consumer have been available since 2.7.x. However you should use 2.9.13; 2.8.x is no longer supported as OSS. https://spring.io/projects/spring-kafka#support 2.9.x is fully compatible with Boot 2.7.x.